# Why isn't my addToList method working right?

Tags: c, string, file, list, text-files

I'm new here and this is my first question:

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct Person{
        char *vorname;
        char *nachname;
};
typedef struct Person Person;

struct Node{
        Person *data;
        struct Node *next;
};
typedef struct Node Node;
void addToList(Person *p);
void readFile();
Node *start = NULL;

void readFile(){
        FILE *f;
        Person *p;
        char input[501];
        char *line;
        f = fopen("persdat.txt", "r");
        while(fgets(input, 500, f) != NULL){
                line = strtok(input, ";");

                strcpy(p->vorname, line);

                line = strtok(NULL, ";");

                strcpy(p->nachname, line);
                printf("%s wurde eingelesen.\n", p->vorname);
                addToList(p);
                line[0] = '\0';
        }
}
void addToList(Person *p){
        Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        newNode->data = p;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        if (start == NULL){
                start = newNode;
                printf("%s wurde in die Liste eingefügt. (1. Stelle)\n", newNode->data->vorname);
        }else{
                Node *current = start;
                int stelle = 2;
                while(current->next != NULL){
                        printf("Liste wird durchlaufen... aktuelle Person: %s\n", current->data->vorname);
                        current = current->next;
                        stelle++;
                }
                current->next = newNode;
                printf("%s wurde in die Liste eingefügt (%d. Stelle).\n", newNode->data->vorname, stelle);
        }
}
void output(){
        Node *current = start;
        printf("%s\n", current->data->vorname);
    do{
                current = current->next;
                printf("%s\n", current->data->vorname);
                }while (current->next != NULL);

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        printf("\n");
        readFile();
        output();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The struct `Person` has the members `char *vorname` and `char *nachname`.
The struct `Node` has the members `Person *data` and struct `Node *next` (I typedef'ed).
start is the declared list.

Here is the text file I'm using:

```
Daniel;Smith
Florian;Mayne
Michael;Fabour
Manuel;Spoley
Andrea;Bree
Prapot;BumBum
Tobias;Sinkleeser
Nikolaus;Muffed
```

Terminal output:

[image]

The function output() print 8 times `Nikolaus` whereas I would expect it to output the 8 names I inserted in the list, why is that?

Comment: at `readFile`: `Person *p;` and member of Person `vorname` and `nachname` pointing area isn't ensured.

Comment: Hey Don7531 and welcome on Stackoverflow! I copied the content of your links in your post, since the idea of stackoverflow is that the question which helps you today will help others tomorrow, and the question won't be understandable at all once links are dead.

Answer (score 1):

In `readFile()` you are missing to allocate any memory to either the `struct Person` as well as to the `struct Person`'s  members.

So the following

```
void readFile(){
    FILE *f;
    Person *p;
    char input[501];
    char *line;
    f = fopen("persdat.txt", "r");
    while(fgets(input, 500, f) != NULL){
            line = strtok(input, ";");

            strcpy(p->vorname, line);
            ...
```

might better look like:

```
void readFile(){
    FILE *f;
    Person * p = calloc(1, sizeof(*p));
    char input[501];
    char *line;
    f = fopen("persdat.txt", "r");
    while(fgets(input, 500, f) != NULL){
            line = strtok(input, ";");

            p->vorname = strdup(line);
            ...
```

(error checking omitted for the sake of readability)